# JSCH SSH giving me constant Auth err

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I have been spending quite a bit of time trying to get JSCH to work correctly. I am trying to get it to SSH into a host and run a command(`basically sudo su; cd /dir/dir/dir ; sh bashscript.sh`), however, it seems I am plagued with "Auth Failed" every time.

I've enabled JSCH logging:

```
INFO: Connecting to {HOST} port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.53
INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: aes256-ctr is not available.
INFO: aes192-ctr is not available.
INFO: aes256-cbc is not available.
INFO: aes192-cbc is not available.
INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: kex: server: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO: kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
INFO: kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
WARN: Permanently added '{HOST}' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO: Disconnecting from {HOST} port 22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
```

I can not understand why in the world it seems to actually connect to the host, add it to the RSA, then return Auth Fail.

Here is the ssh.java file:

```
public class Ssh {
    private String USERNAME = "USERNAME";

    public void connect(String remoteHost, int remotePort, String cmd) throws JSchException, InterruptedException {
        try {

            JSch.setLogger(new debugLogger());
            JSch jSch = new JSch();

            Session session = jSch.getSession(USERNAME, remoteHost, remotePort);
            session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "privatekey");
            jSch.setKnownHosts("~/.ssh/known_hosts");
            jSch.addIdentity("~/.ssh/id_rsa");
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.connect(30000);

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) channel;
            channelExec.setCommand(cmd);
            channelExec.setErrStream(System.err);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channelExec.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            channelExec.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();

            System.out.println("Exit Code: " + channelExec.getExitStatus());

        } catch (JSchException|IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private static class debugLogger implements Logger{
        static Hashtable name = new Hashtable();
        static{
            name.put(new Integer(DEBUG), "DEBUG: ");
            name.put(new Integer(INFO), "INFO: ");
            name.put(new Integer(WARN), "WARN: ");
            name.put(new Integer(ERROR), "ERROR: ");
            name.put(new Integer(FATAL), "FATAL: ");
        }
        public boolean isEnabled(int level){
            return true;
        }
        public void log(int level, String message){
            System.err.print(name.get(new Integer(level)));
            System.err.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `jSch.addIdentity("~/.ssh/id_rsa");` Does jsch understand `~`?

Comment: From stepping through it, it seems it does. 

I guess the question is, does should that `id_rsa` path be pointed towards the path on the machine i am running from, or the server side? I would assume the machine itself(IE: Running from `localhost`, i should be pathing to '/Users/localhostusername/.ssh/id_rsa', not `/home/serveruser/.ssh/id_rsa`)

Comment: Seems like even providing the actual path just results with `USERAuth fail`

Comment: [Yes, it does understand `~`.](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.51/com/jcraft/jsch/Util.java#487)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems:

```
       session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "privatekey");
```

This should be "publickey":

```
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
```

Once you get that working, your code would hang while reading from the remote channel, because it's not actually starting the remote command. Jsch apparently permits trying to read the channel's output before connecting the channel. You need to add a call to `Channel.connect()` to invoke the command on the remote system:

```
        ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) channel;
        channelExec.setCommand(cmd);
        channelExec.setErrStream(System.err);
        channelExec.connect(); <-- Additional line
```

Comment: That was my problem! Thanks for the answer!